# Multiprocessing Help. BrokenProcessPool Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn the basics of multi-processing in python, and found the following example online which I wanted to practice with.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_something(seconds):    
    print(f' Sleeping {seconds} seconds')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done Sleeping {seconds}'

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(do_something, 1)
    print(f1.result())
```

Fairly simple, I know. However, for some reason when I try and run this, I get the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 19, in 
>       print(f1.result())
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 432, in
>   result
>       return self.__get_result()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 384, in
>   __get_result
>       raise self._exception
>
> BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated
>   abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I can only imagine that `print(f1.result())` raised an exception, e.g. because `f1` does not have a `.result` of right type, or the call to `.result()` crashed.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check if the future is done already:

```
if f1.done():
    print(f1.result())
```